# Unity crashes after parallels tools installation (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: unity, xorg, compiz, 16.04, parallels

I've downloaded and installed Ubuntu 16.04 throught Parallels 11 on my MacBook Pro.

The installation went fine and after reboot I could login and use the graphical interface without problems.

Anyway, the resolution was low and the display aspect ratio wrong, so I installed Parallels Tools as usual to fix these minor issues and activate some of parallels features.

After I installed parallels tools I rebooted my virtual machine and all seemed to be fine (login and unity worked flawless), but after I restarted again unity keeps crashing every time I do the login.

I'm aware this problem (or similar) has already been solved somehow here:

1. [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
2. [Parallels (Tools) 9 & 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449388/parallels-tools-9-14-04)
3. [Unity is broken after Parallels Tools installation in Ubuntu 14.04](http://kb.parallels.com/it/121300)

but none of these methods worked in my case.

In particular:

1. Following the accepted solution in `1` did not work since when I launch `ccsm` from command line it doesn't appear inside graphical interface.
2. Reading the only answer in `2` I realised that I had no `xorg.conf` at all (seems the default behaviour now a days), so I tried `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop` and then `X -configure` and then I reinstalled Parallels Tools with no luck! (NOTE: I had to launch these commands on a clean install since lightdm did not stop properly after I installed Parallels Tools for the first time).
3. Using suggested solution in `3` (even after generating `xorg.conf` as described above) I get an error using `gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins` saying that DBUS could not connect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QUICK AND DIRTY WORK AROUND

Disclaimer: I've found this "solution" by trials and errors, therefore I can't guarantee it's safe. Use it at your own risk.

Background: when Parallels Tools is installed it copies under `/usr/lib/compiz/` a bunch of files with this pattern `libprlcompiz_*_*_*_*.so` (with digits instead of `*`). Those are unity plugins and, as it seems, when unity gets loaded the latest version of this plugin is loaded as well.

Now, in my case it happens that unity tries to load `libprlcompiz_0_9_12_2.so`, which causes the error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

So my catch was to rename this file and hope that the previous plugin version has no bugs (namely `libprlcompiz_0_9_12_1.so`). Open a terminal and:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/compiz/libprlcompiz_0_9_12_2.so /usr/lib/compiz/libprlcompiz_0_9_12_2.so.backup
reboot
```

Now everything should work fine after login.

I still have three parallels related processes appearing in unity side bar after login (with a question mark as icon), which disappear after a while.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I had exactly the same problem and your workaround has worked.

Comment: Great!. You saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed an update of Parallels Version 11.2.0 (32581) and I seems to have a new package of Parallels Tools. It does ***not*** contain the file libprlcompiz_0_9_12_2.so anymore and added some others.
Seems to solve the problem. Unity now starts fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off 3D acceleration, it will work fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)